# SharpDevelop: "Could not find fsi.exe" even when f# is installed

Tags: f#, sharpdevelop

I installed a copy of f# on my machine (on a secondary drive), and when i try to start the F# interactive prompt, it says it could not find fsi.exe. Do i need to copy some files somewhere or something?

Comment: you probably just need to add the installed directory to your PATH variable. Although, when I installed F#, it added it for me.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be more specific with your repro steps? I assume you are using the latest, May 2009 CTP? Also, when you say 'start the F# Interactive prompt' are you talking about launching it from the start menu?

On most machines it will be exactly:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharp-1.9.7.4\bin\fsi.exe"
```

If you did something non-standard it could just be a bug in the installer. E.g., did you override the Program Files folder for your F# installation by passing in a command line parameter to msiexec?

Do a quick search for fsi.exe on your machine (the console F# interactive window) and point your shortcut there.

Comment: I downloaded the MSI installer and directed it to my external drive (which happened to be C: because of a quirk in the install process). When i launch sharpdevelop there's an option to start the F# interactive interpreter, and it says it could not find FSI.exe. Trying the console interpreter, the behavior seemed a little wierd (i had to execute #help;; to get it to actually execute anything).

Comment: Oh, OK. So the problem seems to be with Sharpdevelop. (Which explains a lot because I didn't know what that tag was referring to.) I don't know much about the specifics of that IDE, but it sounds like F# is installed on your system correctly. (e.g., FSI.exe is on your disk) but sharpdevelop isn't launching it correctly. That is, sharp develop is reporting the error not FSI or Visual Studio. Correct?

As for the command line FSI, you end all input with two semicolons (;;) so to enter a simple command use "let x = 1;;" or to exit use "#q;;".

Comment: Something like that. Anyway, it builds stuff fine so i guess i'll accept this.

Answer (score 7):

You could try to look here:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\F#\<fsharp_version>\Framework\<dotnet_version>\Fsi.exe"
```

Answer (score 4):

With the VS 15.8 update it appears to have been moved. I found it in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\fsi.exe
```